# store the value on crystal report c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am Facing an issue with crystal report.

i have generated a custom formula to calculate total attendance hours.
the formula code is :

```
if({Atendances.Status} = "OUT") then
DateDiff("h",Previous({Atendances.Time}),{Atendances.Time});
```

and result i am getting

```
1/5/2015 ___________________________

Time                 || Status 
1/5/2015  11:06:00AM || IN
1/5/2015   3:06:00PM || OUT
1/5/2015   4:06:00PM || IN
1/5/2015   7:06:00PM || OUT

Total Hours :  3.00
```

the number 3.00 is the result of the formula and it supposed to be 7.00 hours
the problem is there is no summation or storing of the result value.

i tried to define variables but the result will be 0.0

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula resets every time a new records in so the only value hold is the last.

You need to create a variable and then increment it
this create a variable :

```
Shared NumberVar TotalTime;
```

then you need to put that in a formula and drop it in the report header so it declare it at the beginning.

Now what you need is the formula you currently have and you need to make a reference to that variable and use it. You do his like so :

```
Shared NumberVar TotalTime; // this refers to the variable
TotalTime:= TotalTime + 1 // this increment whatever value of it by 1
```

so all you need to do if add you if statement after the reference to the variable then if it's true calculate the time and increment to the variable. then at last to display the value in the report footer as an example you create another formula with :

```
Shared NumberVar TotalTime; // this refers to the variable
TotalTime; // this simply return the value as a normal formula
```

Comment: Ok but still am getting 0.0 on the group footer , i have created on the group header : [total_time_variable] with code : Shared NumberVar TotalTime;  , and on the group body [total_time_calc] with code : NumberVar TotalTime;
if({Atendances.Status} = "OUT") then
TotalTime:= TotalTime + DateDiff("h",Previous({Atendances.Time}),{Atendances.Time}) , and on group footer [total_time_result] with code : NumberVar TotalTime;
TotalTime; , the result am getting is 0.0 on the group footer ? thanks for your support

Comment: sorry my mistake they have to be declared as shared all the way. I never used datediff but it the result is of date type we need to use `DateVar` instead

Comment: also by using group you need another formula. you need on to drop on the group header to set the value of total time to 0 to reset because the variable exist for the length of the report. so `Shared NumberVar TotalTime; TotalTime:= 0` and the formula that display it put in the group footer and it will work perfectly too.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure I am missing something but it seems to me it would be easier to use summaries which are already in Crystal.
Make sure your records are sorted by time ascending which it probably already is.
It looks like your report is grouped by date field? or maybe even first by Attendant?
So create one formula

```
if {Atendances.Status} = "OUT" 
then DateDiff("h",Previous({Atendances.Time}),{Atendances.Time}) 
else 0
```

Drop this in the details section and create a summary to group footer 1 or 2 or wherever else you want it. Then delete it from details section.